# Get data with 2 tables

Tags: sql, join

I have table1 from which i want to get some columns but column id from table1 must be same as column id from table2

Something like this:

```
Select title, image, price 
from table1 
where id = id from table2
```

Comment: `Select title,image,price from table1 where id IN (SELECT id FROM table2)`

Comment: @lad2025 this looks easy :D thanks

Comment: @lad2025 oh i try it and it didnt work :(

Answer (score 0):

You could use an inner join

```
SELECT title,image,price from table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id
```

I think it's odd that your foreign key on table2 has a name (id) that imply a primary key, unless you want to join two primary keys to create a table partition.